# We have "Here" and "There", why not "Hen" and "Then"?

Tags: etymology, wh-questions

There’s an easy morphological connection between question nouns (What, When, Where) and the “nonlocal” answer (That, Then, There), but the “local” answers vary more substantially (This, Now, Here). Poking around etymonline and wiktionary hasn’t given me a clear idea of why that should be the case; does anyone know?

In table form:

| ? | local | nonlocal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| What | This* | That |
| Where | Here | There |
| Whither | Hither | Thither |
| Whence | Hence | Thence |
| When | Hen? | Then |

Why “now” instead of “*hen”?

Regarding "This", [etymonline shows](https://www.etymonline.com/word/this) the morphological relationship between "this" and "that", noting "this" is "...probably from a North Sea Germanic pronoun *tha-si-, formed by combining the base *þa- (see that) with -s"

Comment: This is an interesting question, but the title lets it down.  At face value, you'd just look at it and say *"It's 'Now', obviously - this is more suited to ELL or something".*

Comment: Perhaps people don't want to bother with *hen*, which is an obsolete word meaning *hence*, *henceforth*  or *from now on*.

Comment: I'd like to see this more fully fleshed out with whence, hence, thence, and whither, hither, thither as well.

Comment: @Clare *Hen* (adverb) was not even close to *then* in Old English. *Then* was spelled þonne/þanne/þænne, while *hen* (adverb) was spelled hionane/heonane/heonone/ hinan/hionan/heonan/heonon/heonun/ hiona/heona. But one spelling of *hen* (noun) in OE is henne and one spelling of *hang* in OE is honne, so there would've still been homographs.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. Please correct the title to accurately reflect your etymological enquiry.

Comment: Do you also wonder why _this_ isn't _hat_?

Comment: after some more research it seems that "now" is derived nearly unchanged from PIE *nu, and "then" in the sense of "at that time" might not have existed until Middle or early Modern English. That leaves me with more questions than answers, so I'm leaving this open for now in case some knowledgeable soul appears

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603965/2085).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Now & Then

In a comment you said:

> [A]fter some more research it seems that "now" is derived nearly unchanged from PIE *nu

This is true (although the spelling has quite obviously changed). Because PIE is a reconstructed language (and nobody ever wrote it down), the proof that this is the case lies in the fact that *nu has many, many cognates in other languages. From the OED:

> Cognate with Old Frisian nū , Middle Dutch nu , nou , noe (Dutch nu ), Old Saxon nu , nū (Middle Low German nū , German regional (Low German) nu ), Old High German nu , nū , no , nō (Middle High German nu , nū , nun , nūn , German nu (now chiefly regional), nun ), Old Icelandic nú , Norn (Shetland) nu , Old Swedish nu (Swedish nu ), Danish nu , Gothic nu < the same Indo-European base as Hittite nu , Sanskrit nu , nū , Avestan nū , ancient Greek (enclitic) νυ , Gaulish nu , Early Irish nu , nú , Welsh †nu (13th cent.), Tocharian A nu , Tocharian B no , Latvian nu , Albanian -ni (in tani ), and (with nasal extension) ancient Greek νῦν , classical Latin num , Old Church Slavonic nyně , Russian nyne , Lithuanian nūn , and (with further extension) classical Latin nunc , probably ultimately related to the Indo-European base of new adj. Also as present tense verbal prefix in Early Irish nu-, no- and as affirmative particle in Welsh †neu (12th cent.).

In a comment, you said:

> "[T]hen" in the sense of "at that time" might not have existed until Middle or early Modern English

This is... not true. There were two words that had this meaning in Old English, *þa* ("[tho](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tho#Etymology_2)") and *þonne* ("then"):

> **Þa** foron hie siþþan æfter þæm wealda hloþum & flocradum. bi swa hwaþerre efes swa hit **þonne** fierdleas wæs. (ChronA 894.11)
>
> ‘**Then** they went afterwards through the woods in bands and troops, on whichever side it **then** was without an army.’
>
> <sub>[Connective or “disconnective” discourse marker? Old English *þa*, multifunctionality and narrative structuring](http://www.helsinki.fi/varieng/series/volumes/08/warvik/)</sub>

OED says *then* is an "adverbial [formation] from the demonstrative root *þa-*".

OED indicates that *þa* has a similar etymology:

> originally a case-form of the demonstrative stem *þa-* of *the* adj., pron.2, and n.2, *that* pron.1, adj., and adv.

*Þa* was the third most used word in Old English, and was used for quite a bit more than just *then*:

> > **Þa** (1) hie **þa** (2) hamweard wendon mid þære herehyþe, **þa** (3) metton hie micelne sciphere wicenga, & **þa** (4) wiþ **þa** (5) gefuhton þy ilcan dæge, & **þa** (6) Deniscan ahton sige; (ChronA 885.10)
> >
> > ‘**When** (1) they **then** (2) returned homeward with that booty, **then** (3) they met a large fleet of pirates, and **then** (4) fought against **them** (5) the same day, and **the** (6) Danes had the victory.’
>
> In this example, we find þa appearing as a conjunction (1), an adverb (3, 4), pronoun (5), and demonstrative determiner (6). The second instance of þa (2) is either an adverb in the subclause introduced by the conjunction þa (1) or the second member of a doubled conjunction þa þa, which can be separated from the first member by an inserted element, though the two members mostly appear together.
> <sub>[Connective or “disconnective” discourse marker? Old English *þa*, multifunctionality and narrative structuring](http://www.helsinki.fi/varieng/series/volumes/08/warvik/)</sub>

---

### That, The, There, This, Þonane, Thither...

*That* and *the* were [the same word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_grammar#Definite_articles_and_demonstratives) in Old English.

Like *then*, these words are all derived "from Proto-Germanic *þa, [which in turn is derived] from Proto-Indo-European *to, *te" ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BEe)).

Þonane is an Old English word meaning "thence". This word would come to be spelled *then* or *thenne* in Middle English; [*thence*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/thence) is derived from it.

---

### Here, Hither, Heonan, He, It...

These words are all descended from the Proto-Germanic stem *hi-, which in turn comes from the PIE root **ke-* (also written "*ḱi- ~ *ḱe- ~ *ḱo- or *-ḱe"; see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%E1%B8%B1e)).

*Heonan* is an Old English word meaning "hence". This word would come to be spelled [*hen*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/hen) or *henne* in Middle English; [*hence*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hence) is derived from it.

In Old English, *it*, was often spelled *hit* (which should make the etymological connection more obvious). It is still spelled this way in some dialects, like Scots:

> **Hit** is nae less o an imposition fur a hits guise o freendly assistance.
> <sub>[D Greetin Bairn an D Soond U D Voice](http://www.scottishcorpus.ac.uk/document/?documentid=958)</sub>

---

### Who, What, Where, When, Why, How, Whither, Whether, Whence...

The *wh-* part of these words (plus some others I didn't list) all come from the PIE stem [*kwo](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*kwo-). *How*, while not starting with *wh*, also comes from the same root, according to Etymonline:

> Old English *hu* "how," from Proto-Germanic **hwo* (source also of Old Saxon *hwo*, Old Frisian, Middle Dutch *hu*, Dutch *hoe*, German *wie*, Gothic *hvaiwa* "how"), an adverbial form from PIE root **kwo-*, stem of relative and interrogative pronouns.

This is already covered by another question: [Who, what, where, when, why, how. Why so many "Wh"s?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/26695/191178)