# Is there an etymological reason some "question words" mirror the spelling of "answer words" (When/then, where/there, ...)?

Tags: etymology, wh-questions

There are a few "question words" that mirror their answer words-

- When/Then
- Where/There
- What/That
- Who/Thou (might be stretching it here..)

Do these words have origins where this makes sense, or is this a coincidence?

Comment: Highly related: [We have "Here" and "There", why not "Hen" and "Then"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/416477/191178)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not really etymological reasons, but historical ones. These words come from old paradigms that have been broken up for the most part but still provide some order.

The English *wh*-words all come from the Proto-Indo-European [**kʷo*-](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=k%ca%b7o-), described as "the stem of relative and interrogative pronouns"

- *what, which, where, when, why, how, who, whither, whence, whether*
  [*who* and *how* have lost  /w/ because they contained /u/ already; now they just have /h/ left]

These **kʷo*-words were also in Latin, where they were spelled with the letters QU. Many of them were borrowed into English with the same meanings

- *quis, quid, qui, quo, quantus, qualis* 'who, what, how, why, how much, what kind'
  [change of /kʷ/ to /hw/ is part of Grimm's Law, which happened to Germanic but not Latin]

There are also various other words often answering these questions, as well. They come from the PIE roots **so*- or **to*-, which became TH or H in English:

- *there, then, thither, thence* (distal)
- *here, now, hither, hence* (proximal)

and the demonstrative pronouns, both distal and proximal:

- *this, these* (proximal s/pl) and *that, those* (distal s/pl)

Comment: Your answer starts with "not really" and then appears to provide a perfect etymological explanation (different prefixes are used to indicate different functions in PIE). Am I missing something? (I'm no linguist -- would that not count as etymological?)

Comment: It's not English etymology; it's the history of I-E languages. English is one, but Julius Caesar and Aśoka are not English history,

Comment: May I understand you as "It's not *English* etymology"?

Comment: But do these parallels exist in other languages descended from Latin? I don't notice them in French, for example.

Comment: Question asks why the *suffixes* of interrogatives "wh**en**" (time), "wh**ere**" (place), "wh**at**" (thing) seem to mirror those of adverbs/demonstratives of the same class, i.e. "th**en**" (time), "th**ere**" (place), "th**at**" (thing). This answer here explains the origin of the "wh" and "th" _preffixes_ but does not establish any relation between them nor explains what is it that they are preffixing and why it is so similar. I don't understand how this answers the question in any way. But then again, the OP accepted the answer, so maybe I didn't understand the question?

Comment: @walen Best repeat that comment under the question, where the Original Poster will get pinged and read it.

Comment: @walen this is a fair criticism -  I went into this question assuming it was probably lost to history in some way, so I marked this as the accepted answer since it satisfied my curiousity enough - and there were no other answers.

If somebody else has a more complete answer, I'm happy to change it though!

Comment: One could write books about those roots (not prefixes, btw) and indeed there are already plenty of books on them. I didn't even get into the paradigms involved, or the source vs goal case markings of _thence_ and _thither_. For further facts, consult David Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_, or _of Language_.