# Why do we spell the word “who” with a silent “w” when it isn’t needed?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, silent-letters

If we spelled *who* without the W – making it *ho* like with *do* and *to* — it could still make sense, so why is there a silent W in the word *who*?

Comment: Because etymology. It's *wer* in German, and the W is still pronounced. English is a Germanic language. That said, note how there is no such thing as a "silent letter", or rather, all letters are always silent. In all languages. Spoken language comes first. Only then do you try to come up with a writing system. Which has to encode way more than just spelling. E.g. etymology. As in this case right here. The spelling used to reflect the actual pronunciation, but no longer does. Given enough time, it will get reformed, but by that time the pronunciation will have moved on further still.

Comment: To add to the confusion, in BrE the words "what" and "where" etc are sometimes pronounced as if the **w** and **h** are reversed: "h-wot". This is no stranger than the AmE pronunciation of "buoy" where the same can happen and they sometimes say "boo-ee" whereas in BrE this rhymes with "boy".

Comment: @RegDwigнt Hover over "add a comment" and you'll see "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." Perhaps you'd like to promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: @WeatherVane - Dead smack in the middle of the USA here, in probably the Nation's capital of Bass Boats. I've heard "boo-ee", but usually I hear it pronounced rhyming with "boy", "toy", and the British greeting "Oi!"

Comment: Because the W is not actually silent, just very quiet?  And "who" is not pronounced at all like "ho" (gettospeak for prostitute).  It's pronounced much more like "hoo" - the sound an owl conventionally makes, at least in US English.  In any case, English spelling is not phonetic, which allows us to distinguish between homonyms and near-homonyms.

Comment: @WeatherVane The OED says *buoy*  is phonemically Brit. /bɔɪ/, /bwɔɪ/,  U.S. /ˈbui/, /bɔɪ/. What happened is that the /w/ in /bw/ was lost just as the /w/ was lost in /hw/ for precisely same reason: it was followed by a back vowel as [John Lawler mentions in his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/483815). Metathesis can have moved /bwoi/ to /bowi/, or even simple deletion followed by a glide pivot, so it’s no surprise that became [bowi] and then [buwi] or [bui], just like what happens in many pronunciations of *bowie-knife*.  Plenty of folks say both *buoy* and *bowie* the same there.

Comment: @tchrist thanks — I did qualify my comment about pronunciation with "sometimes". It's rare to hear the posh way of saying "what" too.

Comment: @T.E.D. I did say "sometimes" because I have occasionally heard it. Note that "oi!" is not a [greeting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/greeting), but a rude way of demanding someone's attention, different in usage from "yo!"

Comment: @WeatherVane On the subject of buoy, as someone from the American South, I've literally never once heard it said any other way than "boo-ee".  And I'm a middle-aged man who's lived near the water my entire life.

Comment: @Haydentech - Doesn't shock me in the slightest. You all are in a different accent area (SAE instead of AmE-Midlands), and SAE in general loves an option that adds extra syllables to a one syllable word.

Comment: @WeatherVane Note that the pronunciation you mention of _what/where_ is not “as if the **w** and **h** are reversed” – that would give something like [hwɒt, hwɛː] (or whatever variant of syllable-final /t/ is used). What it actually is is a /w/ pronounced with no voicing: [ʍɒt, ʍɛː]. It’s not uncommon to denote either aspiration or voicelessness by writing an h after the ‘base’ consonant, though _wh_ is the only case of it in English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I did mean the pronunciation demonstrated in [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/RyCXAYBi9HU). I had no idea that some AmE speakers pronounce **wh** in the way that BrE speakers sometimes do.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think [ʍ] exists as a variant in most major variants of the Anglosphere, except perhaps Indian English. My point, which was perhaps not very well-phrased, was that [ʍ] is no more _hw_ than it is _wh_: it’s not one sound after the other in either order. If anything, it’s a **combination** of [h] and [w], which is why it has its own symbol in IPA.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Or perhaps another way to say it is that nobody ever _creates_ a spelling where they _intentionally make_ a letter "silent". "Silent" letters virtually _always_ were _spoken_ letters in the past, and _time_ has stolen away their voice.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMopBpOfv_E&t=55

Answer (score 37):

The spelling "who" was originally used simply because, in past time periods, this word was pronounced with a "wh" sound. To be clear, by "a "wh" sound" I mean a sound that is different from either "w" or "h" on its own. Although many varieties of English have lost "wh" as a distinct sound, replacing it with plain [w], the digraph "wh" used to (and in some accents still does) have a value that can be transcribed as /hw/, or written with the special symbol [ʍ] if we interpret it as a single sound.

Many aspects of modern English spelling derive from Middle English pronunciation. Analogy with the spelling of other words probably contributed to the continued use of "wh" in spelling even after people started pronouncing the word with a simple /h/ sound. "Who" is one of the many [question words starting with wh-](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26695/who-what-where-when-why-how-why-so-many-whs/26700#26700) in English.

Here is a brief explanation of why *who* lost its /w/ sound. The sound [w] is made by rounding the lips. The pronunciation of the word "who" evolved over time to have a rounded vowel sound, and the presence of a rounded vowel sound caused people to stop hearing a separate rounded consonant at the start of the word. This has happened in other words, most obviously *two.*

The question word *how* lost its /w/ sound for a similar reason, but much earlier, so it has a spelling without "wh".

Unfortunately, irregular spellings in English aren't always etymological. Because of the confusion between "h" and "wh" before rounded vowels, a few words pronounced with a simple /h/ sound are spelled with "wh" before "o" even though, from an etymological perspective, they would be expected to just have "ho". An example is *whole,* which is etymologically related to *heal.*

---

A few blog posts that relate to topics brought up in the comments:

- "[Hwæt about WH?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3085)", by Mark Liberman, 2011 April 13
- "[The Secret Ways of Weak Forms: Here Comes a New ’Un](http://langevo.blogspot.com/2013/02/the-secret-ways-of-weak-forms-here.html)", by Piotr Gąsiorowski, 2013 February 07

Comment: The _wh_ sound may be phonemically transcribed as /hw/, but I would consider it quite misleading to transcribe it thus phonetically – there is no doubt that it is a single sound. [hw] would be an unvoiced [h] followed by a voiced [w], and that is not found anywhere in English; it is, in fact, extremely difficult to produce at all without adding a prop vowel.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Resonants in English are typically devoiced when they come after a voiceless consonant in an onset. I don’t think anyone analyzes /hj/ as in “huge” as a unitary phoneme, even though one possible realization of this sequence is apparently a voiceless palatal fricative. I guess [hw] might be a bit questionable phonetically but I think it works as a broad transcription

Comment: Even if devoicing is allowed for in broad transcription, [hw] and [hj] still both describe _two_ subsequent sounds, which neither is in practice. Phonemically, I have no problem with it – multiple phonemes can and do coalesce into single sounds all the time, after all – but phonetically, it’s as misleading to me as transcribing the standard American /r/ as [wɹ].

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, the OED says that the spelling <wh> in *whole* does correspond to a /hw/ or /w/ pronunciation, that arose in the 15th century, and that may still be found in some dialects. (It adds that the same is even true of some <ho-> words where the original spelling in <h> and standard pronunciation in /h/ eventually won out; there are apparently dialects where e.g. *home* and *hoard* are pronounced with /w/.)

Comment: When I pronounce /hw/ in my dialect (where it is optional), it definitely feels like two sounds. There is the initial aspiration (through tightly rounded lips), then the voiceless glide that becomes voiced just before the vowel is set. For /w/ (even when whispered and thus unvoiced), it seems the sounds starts on the glide.

Answer (score 9):

> Why is the `W` silent in the word *Who*?

It's a long story (as @chaslyfromUK points out, it comes from [a PIE root](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=k%CA%B7o-), which means it's been around on people's lips for over 4000 years), but the short of it is that Germanic languages like English changed /kʷ/ in PIE words to /hʷ/ or /xʷ/. English words beginning with `WH`, which used to be spelled `HW`, also used to be pronounced with much more friction than today -- like `CH`, the *ach-Laut*, the sound in the German word *ach*. English words like *whale* and *wail* did not start with the same consonant sound then -- today, for most Americans and some UK English speakers, they do.

The `H` part of the English `WH` words went away in most cases, like *where, when, why, whether, which, what, whence,* and *whither*; that was part of the change from Middle to Modern English. The old /x/ sounds that were allophones of /h/ went silent; they were spelled `GH` and our Middle English spelling system keeps them for luck or something.

In the cases of *how* and *who*, however, it was the `W` part of `WH` that went away. These two Middle English words contained back rounded vowels /u:/ in *how* and /o:/ in *who*, and if you've ever tried to pronounce words like *woo* or *woad* carefully you know that it's very hard to make the `W` part distinctive. This is because the sound /w/ is made simply by rounding the lips tightly, and they are already tightly rounded in making the vowels /u:/ and /o:/.

A consonant that can't be heard is often not written, and after a while nobody bothers.
That's all, really.

Comment: Same reason why *whole* and *whore* have only /h/ left, although *whoop, whooping* is less settled out, being sometimes /h/ in the crane or cough, but being /hw/ merged to /w/ in the interjection *whoops*.

Comment: @tchrist _whole_ was never pronounced with a /w/. The "w" was added 15c. Similarly with _whore_, the "w" was added 16c.

Comment: @CJDennis I knew there were spellings of *whore* without *w*, but I apparently misrecalled the direction. That's almost silly for them to have done that if it wasn't reflected in the pronunciation.

Comment: It was downright silly of them. But don't forget that _silly_ didn't always mean the same thing, either.

Answer (score 9):

One of the oldest surviving works in any form of English is Beowulf. Here is the first page of the manuscript:

[image: Beowulf page 1]

The first line is:

> Hƿæt Ƿe garde

which in more modern letters is:

> Hwæt We garde

since the ancient letter wynn (Ƿ ƿ) is now represented by double-u (W w).

The first word is "hwæt", which is related to the modern "what" and would have been pronounced "hwat" (to rhyme with "at"). In Middle English, we switched the "h" and "w" around in our spelling, although many speakers continued to pronounce the initial /h/ well into the 20th century.

"Who" is one of the "six Ws" question words:

- who /huː/
- what /wɒt/
- where /wɛə(ɹ)/
- when /wɛn/
- why /waɪ/
- how /haʊ/

For each of the above words starting with /w/, there are some people who still pronounce them starting with /ʍ/ (i.e. /hw/) instead, although this is becoming increasingly rare. All of these words at one point were pronounced starting with /ʍ/.

Wiktionary summarises [how "who" became /huː/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/who#Etymology) nicely:

> From [...] Old English hwā [...] Spelling change *hw* > *wh* in Middle English (without sound change in initial consonant cluster), while sound change /hw/ > /h/ due to *wh*-cluster reduction after a bizarre instance of three consecutive vowel shifts of /aː/ to /ɔː/ to /oː/ in Middle English and further to /uː/ in Early Modern English (although only the shift from /ɔː/ to /oː/ is unusual). Compare *how*, which underwent this change earlier (in Old English), and thus is spelt *h*.

Comment: *What* rhymes not with *caught* and *fought* but rather with *shut* and *mutt* in America, so /wʌt/ or for some speakers /ʍʌt/. It is not have the rounded [ɒ] that UK speakers have in CLOTH.

Comment: @tchrist For me, _what_ rhymes with neither _caught_ nor _cut_, but with _cot_. I just picked one major pronunciation so as to not clutter the answer.

Comment: Does "Hwæt We garde" mean "What we did"?

Comment: @md2perpe The first three words with modern punctuation are "Hwæt! We Gar-Dena" with the "-na" at the start of the second line. It means "Hark! We Spear-Danes ..." The sentence is completed by the first word on the fourth line. If you look carefully, you can see a few full stops in the manuscript.

Answer (score 5):

There is no point in trying to make sense of English spelling. The reasons are often lost in history. English has undergone many transformations. Here is probably the best explanation you will get.

> who (pron.) Old English hwa "who," sometimes "what; anyone, someone;
>   each; whosoever," from Proto-Germanic *hwas (source also of Old Saxon
>   hwe, Danish hvo, Swedish vem, Old Frisian hwa, Dutch wie, Old High
>   German hwer, German wer, Gothic hvo (fem.) "who"), from PIE root
>   *kwo-, stem of relative and interrogative pronouns.
>   https://www.etymonline.com/word/who#etymonline_v_7978

Comment: Making sense of English spelling is fascinating! There is a reason for everything, although sometimes that reason is lost in history, as you say. If you know a word has French or Latinate origins, that goes far to explain its spelling. Likewise with words of Germanic (Anglic, Old Norse) origins or Greek origins. They all help understand our often complex modern spelling system.

Comment: Thankfully, not for some words are the reasons lost in history. Millenial old roots still can be traced if they are say from PIE languages. "*kaha* (कः)  means who in masculine form" https://learnsanskritonline.com/lessons/simple-pronoun-he-she-it-and-they

Comment: By "There is no point" maybe you mean "It is very very hard" ?