# Why did "which" lose its L (it was "hwilch")?

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change

It appears that the word **which** originally had an L in its spelling as well as pronunciation. But its modern pronunciation doesn't have an L.

[Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/which) has:

> From Middle English *which, hwic, wilche, **hwilch**, whilk, **hwilc***, from Old English *hwelċ* (“which”)

- One of its Middle English form *hwilc*'s [pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hwilc#Middle_English) is **/xwilt͡ʃ/ ([ʍiɫt͡ʃ]**).
- Its Old English *hwelc*'s [pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hwelc#Old_English) is **/xwelt͡ʃ/ ([ʍeɫt͡ʃ])**

<sup>[Transcriptions from Wikitionary]</sup>

[Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/which) also agrees on **hwilc** but doesn't explain the loss of the L.

[This Google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=L3JKAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22hwel%C4%8B%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwsuLew5PtAhUux4sKHdCDAHsQ6AEwCXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=hwilc&f=false) shows some uses of "hwilc" and also records the spelling **hwylc**

The change from **hw** to **wh** is answered in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483812/why-do-we-spell-the-word-who-with-a-silent-w-when-it-isn-t-needed) (John Lawler's answer seems reasonable), but I didn't find any related question about the loss of the L.  I also didn't find any other source for it.

**Why did it lose the L? Is there a good reason for it or is it a random loss?**

Answer (score 1):

Much of English is Germanic in origin. German retains the "l" in "welche" (which).

I suspect that there is a tendency in English to lose sounds that aren't needed - especially in common words. You can put this down to laziness. Of course there are many words that retain their old spelling but are pronounced differently today. https://www.grammarly.com/blog/words-that-are-not-pronounced-how-they-are-spelled/

Note that, during the 20th century, the word "which" lost its "hw" sound in many places. Now in England I hear only the pronunciation "wich" although in parts of Scotland the "hw" is preserved. Maybe one day "wich" will become the normal spelling.

We can see this in "could" where the "l" is silent. There is no clear reason for "which" to lose the "l" and for "could" to retain it, albeit silently.  English spelling is something of a lottery.

People have been trying to regularise English spelling for over a hundred years. I suspect this will happen naturally owing to the proliferation of phonetic spellings on social media.

Comment: "I suspect that there is a tendency in English to lose sounds that aren't needed - especially in common words." /// Sure, but *hwilc* is a special case. Why special? Because of the L. When L is followed by another consonant, it usually gets [velarised (dark l) and then **vocalised**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/547425/365490) as in *ta**l**k, wa**l**k, pa**l**m, ha**l**f, ca**l**m* etc. I suspect the same thing happened in *hwilc*; the *l* got velarised before [t͡ʃ] and then vocalised. But I don't have any source to support my answer with.

Comment: Interesting point about the L in ***could***. I just learned a new word from [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/could) when I checked it out: *The **unetymological** -l- was added 15c.-16c. on model of would, should, where it is historical.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Or alternatively, by [analogy](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/106592) with *would, should*.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: Indeed. So really I should just accept that whoever wrote that particular text on the etymonline page wasn't the most "careful" speaker/writer (***by analogy with***, ***[based] on the model of***, or ***modeled on*** all work for me, but not the actual choice made). But I *want* to "trust" it - simply because I like the possibility of being able to bandy ***unetymological*** about in future! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And all this time I'd thought *could* was how you Brits spell *cold*: analogous to *mould*, etc. ^_^

Comment: @FF Does this pave the way for an unetymological fallacy?